# How to show that if x is a cluster point of a filter then it a cluster point of each of its associated or derived net.

Tags: general-topology, limits, convergence-divergence, filters, nets

Am stuck with this problem. However I am able to show the other way round. Please help me wih it.

Comment: First, write down the definitions.  In particular "associated or derived" net.  (Writing the definitions is a good way to start any problem where you are stuck.)

Answer (score 0):

Typically **the** associated net to a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ has as its index set

$$I= \{(F,x) \in \mathcal{F} \times X\mid x \in F\}$$ with order

$$(F_1,x) \le_I (F_2,x') \iff F_2 \subseteq F_1$$

which is directed as a filter is closed under finite intersections.

The net $n: I \to X$ is then simply defined as the projection $n((F,x))=x$.

(maybe the OP allows more of such associated nets on just the index set of reverse-inclusion $\mathcal{F}$, but then choice is required to get such a net; IMO this is more "canonical").

Suppose $p$ is a cluster point of $\mathcal{F}$ which means

$$\forall O \in \mathcal{N}_p: \forall F \in \mathcal{F}: F \cap O \neq \emptyset\tag{1}$$

(or equivalently, $p \in \bigcap \{\overline{F}\mid F \in \mathcal{F}\}$).
Now we will show $p$ is also a cluster point of the net $n$: let $O$ be any neighbourhood of $p$ and $i_1 = (F_1,x)$ be any member of $I$, we must find a larger member $i_2$ of $I$ such that $n(i_2) \in O$ (the net must be *frequently* in all neighbourhoods of $p$).

Applying $(1)$ to $O$ and $F_1$ we find $y \in O \cap F_1$. But then trivially $i_2 = (F_1,y) \in I$ and also $i_1 \le_I i_2$ and $n(i_2)= y \in O$. So we are already done.

It's basically almost "true by definitions"; nothing deep.

**Added after comments**

If any net $n$ on $\mathcal{F}$ (ordered by reverse inclusion) to $X$, such that $n(F) \in F$ for all $\mathcal{F}$, counts as *an* associated net of $\mathcal{F}$, the statement must be adapted I think. It's *not* true (see example by OP in a comment) that for *all* associated nets to $\mathscr{F}$, $p$ must be a cluster point of $n$, but we maybe could say that this is the case for *some* associated net. The "canonical" associated net above *does* work, but we cannot claim for all in the general definition.

So in that case the general statement from the title of the question is false.

Comment: Thank you so much Henno actually I am using only the sets of script F as the directed index set, so I am facing problem in taking the element of the non void intersection as an element of the net.

Comment: @PromitMukherjee I added an argument for that definition too.

Comment: Thanks but here I am facing problem to understand, why n(F2)∉O implies p is not a limit point of F1,in  O there may be an element of F1 other than n(F2) s. How to clarify this point?

Comment: I think for the definition of associated net using  the directed set with only the sets of script F, with reverse inclusion, the result will not be true for each such associated net. For example

Comment: If we take script F as the collection of all closed sets containing [1,2] then it clearly forms a filtet in R with usual topology. Now 2 is a cluster point of this filter as 2 is in all the memebers of script F. But if we make a net as n(F)=1 for all F from the directed set script F, and take O=(1.5,2.5) an open set containing 2 then n(F)=1∉O for all F. Therefore 2 is not a cluster point of the associated net created in the above manner. How about this example? So I think your first definition is alright but the result will not hold true for ordinary set definition.

Comment: @PromitMukherjee I think you're right and the statement from the question's title is false.  It is *not* the case that $p$ is a cluster point of every associated net to $\mathscr{F}$. If $p$ is the cluster point of *some* associated net, it will be a cluster point of $\mathscr{F}$ (quite clear from the definitions), and your example fits with that..